# Charge events are firing in live mode but returning as test

Tags: plugin-charge, stripe

I am having a major issue with craft subscription. All data in stripe shows it as live mode and in craft it is showing as test payment. Also the subscription url points to `https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/plans/plan-name-here` instead of `https://dashboard.stripe.com/plans/plan-name-here`

if someone has run into the problem please shed some light

Comment: The plugin never seemed to be finished and it just is coded incorrectly when it comes to this functionality. It's happening for me on a live and working site, so you can just ignore it. That being said Craft Commerces native subscription functionality is going to be a welcome addition to Craft. If you need anything custom or fixed with Charge Fred Carlson (@suberbig) is the man to ask.

Comment: What version are you on? This was working fine last time I worked with it.